# sklearn: silhouette_score MemoryError sparse input

Tags: scipy, scikit-learn

I am calling `silhouette_score`, passing in a sparse matrix as X. The error I am getting is `MemoryError`. Looking at the Stack Trace, I see something like:

```
...
packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py", line 245, in euclidean_distances
        distances = safe_sparse_dot(X, Y.T, dense_output=True)
...
site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py", line 496, in _mul_sparse_matrix
indices = np.empty(nnz, dtype=idx_dtype)
MemoryError
```

I see that when calling `safe_sparse_dot` `dense_output=True`. My initial thought is that this is the cause of the MemoryError. There seems to be no way to specify this parameter when calling `silhouette_score`.

Could this be the cause of the issue or am I barking up the wrong tree? Or does sklearn have some rationale for always passing `dense_output=True`?

Comment: The error is occurring when it is trying to make a new sparse matrix, one with `nnz` nonzero terms.  What's the size of `X` and `Y`?  Either they are very large, or their `dot` is creating a rather dense large matrix.

Comment: `X` and `Y` are 500,000 rows x ~2000 columns, but they are quite sparse (each row is on average about 98% sparse). So the answer to your first question is that they are quite large. The second scenario I'm not so sure about. Shouldn't the dot be sparse if the input is sparse? That's what I would expect.

Comment: So the `dot` dimension is (500000, 500000)? 2% of that is still large, 5e9.